# apple mach-O linker (id) error with open cv 3.2.0

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv

I installed OpenCV 3.2.0-dev on my mac(10.12) using Homebrew following this instruction http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/.

I solved the **QTKit.h** problem by skipping the **checkout** step.

Then I tried to build a small c++ program in Xcode 8 because I'm more familiar with c++ than python, it gave me an Apple mach-O linker (id) error which is shown here:
[error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mweeq.png)

The search paths for header and library are */usr/local/include* and */usr/local/lib* respectively. And the linker flags are

-lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_videostab

And I know when I use OpenCV version later than 3.1(I think), the linker flags can be replaced by something like opencv_world310.lib. Is there a similar way in Xcode?

Anyone can help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Homebrew install opencv in `/usr/local/Cellar/`, not in `/usr/local/`. So you need to modify header and library search paths correspondingly.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. Now the paths have been changed to /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/HEAD-2341222_4/.... But the error is still there...Any idea?

Comment: That capture tells very little about the error. Also, for Xcode it is recommended that you add (references of) the libraries into your project.